# spring boot + hibernate Can I use entityMnager.persist(item) after I get the item with named query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, named-query

I am using spring boot and hibernate. I have a named query where I select an item. Then I want to set some property and then to make entityManager.persist() or entityManager.merge(). Can I do this or the instance of my item will be unmanaged after the named query and persist/merge will fail ?

Here is my code where em.persist() actually do not work:

```
public String getSMSText(String sourceUrl) {

    Rss rss;
    List urls = em.createNamedQuery("Rss.getFeedByUrl").setParameter("url", sourceUrl).getResultList();
    if (urls.size() != 0) {
        rss = (Rss) urls.get(urls.size() - 1);
        for (Rss.Item item : rss.getChannel().getItems()) {
            try {
                if (Utils.isToday(item.getPubDateAsDate()) && !item.isPushed()) {
                    item.setPushed(true);
                    em.refresh(item);
                    em.persist(item);
                    return item.getTitle() + "." + item.getSummary();
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.info("Cannot parse pub date", e);
            }
        }
        logger.info(sourceUrl + " No news for today!");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why bother doing persistence with the entityManager ? Just use Spring data jpa to get your data back and save it, and that will handle all the underlying entity manager calls for you.

Comment: The whole app is made in this way and I just want to fix a bug. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your change on the item will not have any effect.
You should change your item only when the query transaction is completely closed.

I think you have two way:
1- Change your code to update your entity only when you are sure that the select query transaction was closed.
2- Use EntityManager.refresh() on your item, after the named query and before change and persist it.

Comment: that's exactly my problem. I updated my question with code. Even I put em.refresh() before em.persist() it is not working again. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: change the order of item.setPushed(true); and em.refresh(item).
em.refresh(item) will overwrite every change you made on your item, resetting the status as it is on database.
In this case refresh is useful only to be sure that the transaction on namedquery is closed. Then you can made your change and persist it.

Comment: nothing again.. the value still unchanged in the database

Comment: Strange...try to separate, if you can, the select and the update in two different methods